# Change .egg-info directory with pip install --editable

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to modify the location of the .egg-info directory that is generated upon:

`pip install --editable .`

I'm asking because I store my source code on (locally synchronized) cloud storage, and I want to install the package in editable mode on independent computers. So, ideally, the package directory would not be polluted with anything related to a given installation of the package.

I have tried using the `--src` option but this did not work; I don't understand what this option is meant to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the [egg_base](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/commands.html?highlight=egg_info#other-egg-info-options) option to `setup.cfg`:

```
[egg_info]
egg_base = relative/path/to/egg_info_folder
```

I have used this successfully in `pip 19.3.1`.

In my environment, the actual files that this altered are:

- `/anaconda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy-install.pth`
- `/anaconda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/package_name.egg-link`

Note, `pip install` raises an error if the `egg_base` base is not a relative path. But directly altering the files appears to work:

`/anaconda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy-install.pth`:

```
/path/to/repository/folder
```

`/anaconda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/package_name.egg-link`:

```
/path/to/egg_info/folder
/path/to/repository/folder/
```

Comment: Link appears to be outdated. Has this changed in setuptools?

Comment: Ho to do this in pyproject.toml?

Comment: @Stefan Add `egg_base = "_build"` in your `[tool.distutils.egg_info]` section.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still relevant, but here is a `setup.py` based solution: https://jbhannah.net/articles/python-docker-disappearing-egg-info