# dockerised python interpreter complaints about missing package when bind-mounting source over package location in docker

Tags: python, docker, pip

I'm developing a number of python packages that work together. To make my life easier I created a Dockerfile where during build time I copy over sources and then install packages in editable mode like this:

```
cd /path/to/package
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
pip install -e .
```

When I run this environment I mount my local sources over sources copied at the time of creation of the image.

The problem is that I do not install those packages on my host so there are no `.*.egg-info` directories. This causes python interpreter to break when I call `pkg_resources.get_distribution('my_package_name').version` in my package.

I was wondering if it's possible to install a package with pip in editable mode and to store `egg-info` directory outside of my package directory so mounting my host sources over it would not cause python to "forget" about the package.

I did see this blog post: https://jbhannah.net/articles/python-docker-disappearing-egg-info - for legacy reasons I have to use `pip` so this solution will not work in my case

I also did see this question: [Change .egg-info directory with pip install --editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260307/change-egg-info-directory-with-pip-install-editable) but my venv lives outside of package directory so changing the relative path does not lead me to solution of the problem

Comment: Why not just use `/path/to/package/.venv` like usual?

Comment: I need these packages to *see* each other - I have `/path/to/package1`, `/path/to/package2` etc. and one venv where all of them are installed.

Comment: I see.  How about a symbolic link to the egg info, so it's accessible under the mount? You can gitignore it..

Comment: I was thinking about doing something like that in entrypoint at the start of my container. Or copy egg-info away and then either symlink or bind-mount within container. But it feels a bit painful, I was hoping maybe there is better way to achieve this :)