# Store .egg-info directory in venv directory

Tags: python, pip

I create a virtual environment and then install a local package into it in editable mode like this:

```
python3 -m venv --copies venv_dir
source "venv_dir/bin/activate"

python3 -m pip install --config-settings editable_mode=compat --editable ../some_package
```

(I need `--config-settings editable_mode=compat --editable` so that Pyright works.)

This works fine, except that it creates a `.egg-info` directory at `../some_package/some_package.egg-info`.

Unfortunately that causes issues for my build system (and is generally crap because it pollutes the source tree). Is there a way to specify where that `.egg-info` goes - ideally in the `venv_dir`?

Also what exactly is that `.egg-info` directory?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260307/change-egg-info-directory-with-pip-install-editable) has a way for `some_package` itself to specify a different directory within it, but that's not what I'm asking. I want to specify a different directory to `pip` when I install it.

Maybe there's something like

```
python3 -m pip install --local-egg ...
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install --egg=$(pwd)/foo ...
```

`some_package` has a very simple `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "..."
description = "..."
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
dependencies = [
...
]
version = "1.0.0"
```

Comment: I think [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1347) is about this, but nearly everyone there is just trying to clean up the stupid `.egg-info` directory rather than recognising that is a dumb design to put it there in the first place.